# Error - Rabbit Template publish Confirm - reply-code=403, reply-text=ACCESS_REFUSED - cannot publish to internal exchange

Tags: spring-boot, spring-amqp

My Use Case is:

1. subscribe to Q1 and read messages in Batches of specified size.
2. Pass the read message collection for processing.
3. publish the collected messages to Q2 and ack message to Q1 upon sucessful confirmation of q2 publish.

### Code

```java
@Component
public class EPPQ2Subscriber {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EPPQ2Subscriber.class);

    @Autowired
    RabbitMqConfig rabbitMqConfig;

    @Autowired
    AppConfig appConfig;

    List<Message> messageList = new ArrayList<Message>();
    List<Long> diliveryTag = new ArrayList<Long>();
    /**
     * Method is listener's receive message method , invoked when there is message ready to read  
     * @param message - Domain object of message encapsulated 
     * @param channel - rabitmq client channel 
     * @param messageId - @TODO Delete it later.
     * @param messageProperties - amqp message properties contains message properties such as delivery tag etc..
     */
    @RabbitListener(id="messageListener",queues = "#{rabbitMqConfig.getSubscriberQueueName()}",containerFactory="queueListenerContainer")
    public void receiveMessage(Message message, Channel channel, @Header("id") String messageId, 
            MessageProperties messageProperties) {

        LOGGER.info("Result:" + message.getClass() + ":" + message.toString());
        if(messageList.size() <= appConfig.getSubscriberChunkSize() ) {
            messageList.add(message);
            diliveryTag.add(messageProperties.getDeliveryTag());
        } else {
            // call the service here to decrypt, read pan, call danger to scrub, encrypt pan and re-pack them in message again.
            //after this branch messageList should have scrubbed and encrypted message objects ready to publish.

            // Here is call for publish and ack messages..

        }

    }
}

@Component
@Configuration
public class TopicConfiguration {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TopicConfiguration.class);

    @Autowired
    RabbitMqConfig rabbitMqConfig;

    @Autowired EPPQ2Publisher eppQ2Publisher;

    /**
     * Caching connection factory 
     * @return CachingConnectionFactory
     */
    @Bean
    public CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory =  new CachingConnectionFactory(rabbitMqConfig.getPublisherHosts(), rabbitMqConfig.getPublisherPort());
        connectionFactory.setUsername(rabbitMqConfig.getPublisherUsername());
        connectionFactory.setPassword(rabbitMqConfig.getPublisherPassword());

        return connectionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Bean RabbitTemplate
     * @return RabbitTemplate
     */
    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
        final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());

rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(producerJackson2MessageConverter());
            RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
            ExponentialBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new 
            ExponentialBackOffPolicy();
            backOffPolicy.setInitialInterval(500);
            backOffPolicy.setMultiplier(10.0);
            backOffPolicy.setMaxInterval(10000);
            retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);
            rabbitTemplate.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate);
    /*      rabbitTemplate.setExchange(rabbitMqConfig.getPublisherTopic());
            rabbitTemplate.setRoutingKey(rabbitMqConfig.getRoutingKey());*/
            rabbitTemplate.setConfirmCallback((correlation, ack, reason) ->    
            if(correlation != null ) {
             LOGGER.info("Received " + (ack ? " ack " : " nack ") +            
             "for correlation: " + correlation);
                    if(ack) {
                        // this is confirmation received..
                        // here is code to ack Q1. correlation.getId and ack
                        eppQ2Publisher.ackMessage(new 
                       Long(correlation.getId().toString()));
                    } else {
                // no confirmation received and no need to do any                        
                 thing for retry..
                    }
                }

            });
            rabbitTemplate.setReturnCallback((message, replyCode, 
            replyText, exchange, routingKey) -> 
           {
            LOGGER.error("Returned: " + message + "\nreplyCode: " +                                               

    replyCode+ "\nreplyText: " + replyText + 
"\nexchange/rk: " + exchange + "/" + routingKey);
                });
                return rabbitTemplate;
            }

        /**
         * Bean Jackson2JsonMessageConverter
         * @return Jackson2JsonMessageConverter
         */


    @Bean
            public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter producerJackson2MessageConverter() {
                return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
            }

        }

public interface EPPQ2Publisher {
    public void sendMessage(Message msg,Long deliveryTag);
    public void sendMessages(List<Message> msgList, Channel channel, List<Long> deliveryTagList);
    public void ackMessage(Long deliveryTag);
}


@Component
public class EPPQ2PublisherImpl implements EPPQ2Publisher{
    @Autowired
    RabbitMqConfig rabbitMqConfig;

    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    private Channel channel;

    /**
     * Method sendMessage for sending individual scrubbed and encrypted message to publisher queue (Q2).
     * @param msg - message domain object 
     * @param deliveryTag - is message delivery tag.        
     */
    @Override
    public void sendMessage(Message msg,Long deliveryTag) {
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(rabbitMqConfig.getPublisherTopic(), rabbitMqConfig.getRoutingKey(), msg,new CorrelationData(deliveryTag.toString()));
    }

    /**
     * sendMessages for sending list of scrubbed and encrypted messages to publisher queue (Q2)
     * @param msgList - is list of scrubbed and encrypted messages
     * @param channel - is ampq client channel 
     * @param deliveryTagList - is list of incoming message delivery tags. 
     */
    @Override
    public void sendMessages(List<Message> msgList, Channel channel, List<Long>deliveryTagList) {
        if(this.channel == null) {
            this.channel = channel;
        }
        for (int i = 0 ; i < msgList.size(); i ++) {
            sendMessage(msgList.get(i),deliveryTagList.get(i));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method ackMessage for sending acknowledgement to subscriber Q1
     * @param  deliveryTag - is deliveryTag for each individual message.
     */
    @Override
    public void ackMessage(Long deliveryTag)  { 
        try {
            channel.basicAck(deliveryTag, false);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory Creating cached Rabbit Channel from AMQChannel(amqp://**dftp_subscriber**@10.15.190.18:5672/hydra.services,2)

I expected to be dftp_publisher and I guess my topic configuration is not injected properly.

### Error Log:

> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate[0;39m: Executing callback RabbitTemplate$$Lambda$285/33478758 on RabbitMQ Channel: Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://dftp_subscriber@10.15.190.18:5672/hydra.services,2), conn: Proxy@1dc339f Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@2bd7c8 [delegate=amqp://dftp_subscriber@10.15.190.18:5672/hydra.services, localPort= 55553]
>   org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate[0;39m: Publishing message (Body:'{"HEADER":{"RETRY_COUNT":0,"PUBLISH_EVENT_TYPE":"AUTH"},"PAYLOAD":{"MTI":"100","MTI_REQUEST":"100","PAN":"6011000000000000","PROCCODE":"00","PROCCODE_REQUEST":"00","FROM_ACCOUNT":"00","TO_ACCOUNT":"00","TRANSACTION_AMOUNT":"000000000100","TRANSMISSION_MMDDHHMMSS":"0518202930","STAN":"000001","LOCALTIME_HHMMSS":"010054","LOCALDATE_YYMMDD":"180522","EXPIRATION_DATE_YYMM":"2302","MERCHANT_TYPE":"5311","ACQUIRING_COUNTRY_CODE":"840","POS_ENTRY_MODE":"02","POS_PIN_ENTRY_CAPABILITIES":"0","FUNCTION_CODE":"100","ACQUIRING_ID_CODE":"000000","FORWARDING_ID_CODE":"000000","RETRIEVAL_REFERENCE_NUMBER":"1410N644D597","MERCHANT_NUMBER":"601100000000596","CARD_ACCEPTOR_NAME":"Discover Acq Simulator","CARD_ACCEPTOR_CITY":"Riverwoods","CARD_ACCEPTOR_STATE":"IL","CARD_ACCEPTOR_COUNTRY":"840","CARD_ACCEPTOR_COUNTRY_3NUMERIC":"840","NRID":"123456789012345","TRANSACTION_CURRENCY_CODE":"840","POS_TERMINAL_ATTENDANCE_INDICATOR":"0","POS_PARTIAL_APPROVAL_INDICATOR":"0","POS_TERMINAL_LOCATION_INDICATOR":"0","POS_TRANSACTION_STATUS_INDICATOR":"0","POS_ECOMMERCE_TRAN_INDICATOR":"0","POS_TYPE_OF_TERMINAL_DEVICE":"0","POS_CARD_PRESENCE_INDICATOR":"0","POS_CARD_CAPTURE_CAPABILITIES_INDICATOR":"0","POS_TRANSACTION_SECURITY_INDICATOR":"0","POS_CARD_DATA_TERMINAL_INPUT_CAPABILITY_INDICATOR":"C","POS_CARDHOLDER_PRESENCE_INDICATOR":"0","DFS_POS_DATA":"0000000000C00","GEODATA_STREET_ADDRESS":"2500 LAKE COOK ROAD   ","GEODATA_POSTAL_CODE":"600150000","GEODATA_COUNTY_CODE":"840","GEODATA_STORE_NUMBER":"10001","GEODATA_MALL_NAME":"DISCOVER FINANCIAL SR","ISS_REFERENCE_ID":"72967956","ISS_PROCESSOR_REFERENCE_ID":"123459875","VERSION_INDICATOR":"03141"}}' MessageProperties [headers={**TypeId**=com.discover.dftp.scrubber.domain.Message}, contentType=application/json, contentEncoding=UTF-8, contentLength=1642, deliveryMode=PERSISTENT, priority=0, deliveryTag=0])on exchange [hydra.hash2Syphon.exc], routingKey = [100]
>   org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$DefaultChannelCloseLogger[0;39m: Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method(reply-code=403, reply-text=ACCESS_REFUSED - cannot publish to internal exchange 'hydra.hash2Syphon.exc' in vhost 'hydra.services', class-id=60, method-id=40)

---

EDIT 2.

```java
@Component
@Configuration
public class ListenerContainerFactory {

    static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ListenerContainerFactory.class);

    @Autowired
    RabbitMqConfig rabbitMqConfig;

    @Autowired
    EPPQ2Subscriber receiver;

    @Autowired
    EPPQ2ChanelAwareSubscriber receiverChanel;


     public ListenerContainerFactory(ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx) {
        printContainerStartMsg();
    }
    private void printContainerStartMsg() {
        logger.info("----------- Scrubber Container Starts   --------------");
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory queueListenerContainer(AbstractConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
            MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) { 
        connectionFactory.setAddresses(rabbitMqConfig.getSubscriberHosts());
        connectionFactory.setVirtualHost("hydra.services");
        connectionFactory.setPort(rabbitMqConfig.getSubscriberPort());
        connectionFactory.setUsername(rabbitMqConfig.getSubscriberUsername());
        connectionFactory.setPassword(rabbitMqConfig.getSubscriberPassword());
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        factory.setErrorHandler(errorHandler());
        return factory;
    }

     @Bean
     MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(EPPQ2Subscriber receiver) {
         return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver, "receiveMessage");
     }

     /*@Bean
     MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapterWithChanel(EPPQ2ChanelAwareSubscriber receiverChanel) {
         return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiverChanel);
     }*/

     @Bean
        public ErrorHandler errorHandler() {
            return new ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler(fatalExceptionStrategy());
        }

     @Bean
     public  ScrubberFatalExceptionStrategy fatalExceptionStrategy() {
         return new ScrubberFatalExceptionStrategy();
     }
}
```

and Latest Topic Configuration.

```java
@Component
@Configuration
public class TopicConfiguration {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TopicConfiguration.class);

    @Autowired
    RabbitMqConfig rabbitMqConfig;

    @Autowired EPPQ2Publisher eppQ2Publisher;

    /**
     * Bean Queue
     * @return Queue
     */
    @Bean
    Queue queue() {
        return new Queue(rabbitMqConfig.getPublisherQueueName(), false);
    }

    /**
     * Bean TopicExchage
     * @return TopicExchage
     */
    @Bean
    TopicExchange exchange() {
        return new TopicExchange(rabbitMqConfig.getPublisherTopic());
    }
    /**
     * Bean BindingBuilder
     * @param queue - Queue 
     * @param exchange - TopicExchange
     * @return BindingBuilder
     */
    @Bean
    Binding binding(Queue queue, TopicExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(rabbitMqConfig.getRoutingKey());
    }


     /**
     * Caching connection factory 
     * @return CachingConnectionFactory
     */
    @Bean
    public CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(rabbitMqConfig.getPublisherHosts(),
                rabbitMqConfig.getPublisherPort());
        connectionFactory.setUsername(rabbitMqConfig.getPublisherUsername());
        connectionFactory.setPassword(rabbitMqConfig.getPublisherPassword());
        return connectionFactory;
    }



     /**
         * Bean RabbitTemplate
         * @return RabbitTemplate
         */
        @Bean
        public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
            final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(cachingConnectionFactory());
            rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(producerJackson2MessageConverter());
            RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
            ExponentialBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new ExponentialBackOffPolicy();
            backOffPolicy.setInitialInterval(500);
            backOffPolicy.setMultiplier(10.0);
            backOffPolicy.setMaxInterval(10000);
            retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);
            rabbitTemplate.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate);

    /*        rabbitTemplate.setExchange(rabbitMqConfig.getPublisherTopic());
            rabbitTemplate.setRoutingKey(rabbitMqConfig.getRoutingKey());*/
            rabbitTemplate.setConfirmCallback((correlation, ack, reason) -> {
                if(correlation != null ) {
                    LOGGER.info("Received " + (ack ? " ack " : " nack ") + "for correlation: " + correlation);
                    if(ack) {
                        // this is confirmation received..
                        // here is code to ack Q1. correlation.getId() and ack
                        eppQ2Publisher.ackMessage(new 
             Long(correlation.getId().toString()));
                    } else {
                        // no confirmation received and no need to do any      
                    }
                }

            });
            rabbitTemplate.setReturnCallback(
            (message, replyCode, replyText,        
            exchange, routingKey) -> 
            {
                LOGGER.error("Returned: " + message + "\nreplyCode: " + 
              replyCode
                        + "\nreplyText: " + replyText + "\nexchange/rk: " + 
              exchange + "/" + routingKey);
            });
            return rabbitTemplate;
        }

        /**
         * Bean Jackson2JsonMessageConverter
         * @return Jackson2JsonMessageConverter
         */
        @Bean
        public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter producerJackson2MessageConverter() {
            return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you are asking. If you mean the subscriber user doesn't have permissions to write to that exchange, your wiring is wrong.

You don't show the subscriber configuration.

Is it possible the subscriber connection factory bean is also called `connectionFactory`? In that case one or the other will win.

They need different bean named.

Comment: Garry Basically I have 2 questions Here

Comment: Garry Basically I have 2 questions Here.
I have added my Subscriber configuration.
1. Some how my CacheConnnection factory is not getting injected to rabbit template. Because It still show my subscriber username in error log.
2. Both Subscriber and publisher Id's have full permission on the Q and Exchanges. But I am getting connection 
 Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=403, reply-text=ACCESS_REFUSED - access to exchange 'sample.exc' in vhost 'hydra.services' refused for user 'dftp_subscriber', class-id=40, method-id=10)

Comment: As I said, the first one could happen if you have clashing bean names, but you don't show the subscriber configuration, so I can't tell. I don't know how/why rabbit would consider your exchange "internal". You should ask that on the rabbitmq-users Google group; the RabbitMQ engineers monitor that more closely; they only look here from time-to-time.

Comment: Please see Edit 2 ListenerContainerFactory is my subscriber configuration

Comment: I fixed the 2nd issue by Creating new exchange and binding. But still my first question is not resolved . that is injection problem Connection factory and rabbit template from Topic configuration is not used instead Default rabbit template  is been injected. Because ,messages are successfully published to topic but my rabbit-template's call back method is not called.

Comment: I still don't see your subscriber connection factory, you are injecting a `AbstractConnectionFactory` into the factory method. Perhaps post a small project that exhibits this behavior on GitHub? If, I'll take a look; it's hard to see what's wrong otherwise.

Comment: Hi Gray - I tied uploading simple working  project to Git hub, But my laptop does not permits to upload so clearly I am posting my problem in other question.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the permissions for your user if while initiating the consumer/producer we don't have the exchange name it will fallback to default